# Disk space error while aligning reads using STAR

Tags: sam, rna-alignment, star

Hi am trying to align RNA-seq reads using STAR through following commands,

```
STAR --runMode alignReads --runThreadN 26  --outSAMtype BAM  SortedByCoordinate Unsorted --sjdbOverhang 100  --genomeDir wheat --readFilesIn G3_cleaned_R1.fastq G3_cleaned_R2.fastq --sjdbGTFtagExonParentTranscript wheat.gff3 
Jun 05 13:53:59 ..... started STAR run
Jun 05 13:53:59 ..... loading genome
Jun 05 14:07:12 ..... started mapping
Jun 05 18:42:47 ..... started sorting BAM

EXITING because of FATAL ERROR: number of bytes expected from the BAM bin   does not agree with the actual size on disk: 509186583   0   45                                                                                        

EXITING because of FATAL ERROR: number of bytes expected from the BAM bin does not agree with the actual size on disk: 648593301   0   47                                                                                        

Jun 05 18:42:47 ...... FATAL ERROR, exiting                                                                                                                                                                                      
Jun 05 18:42:47 ...... FATAL ERROR, exiting                                                                                                                                                                                      
EXITING because of FATAL ERROR: number of bytes expected from the BAM bin does not agree with the actual size on disk: 660412146   0   46                                                                                        
Jun 05 18:42:47 ...... FATAL ERROR, exiting                                                                                                                                                                                      
EXITING because of FATAL ERROR: number of bytes expected from the BAM bin does not agree with the actual size on disk: 470931698   0   44                                                                                        

Jun 05 18:42:47 ...... FATAL ERROR, exiting                                                                                                                                                                                      
EXITING because of FATAL ERROR: number of bytes expected from the BAM bin does not agree with the actual size on disk: 653155717   0   43                                                                                        

Jun 05 18:42:47 ...... FATAL ERROR, exiting                                                                                                                                                                                      
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Although there is much free space on my system as shown below:

```
> df -Th
  Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
  devtmpfs       devtmpfs   63G     0   63G   0% /dev
  tmpfs          tmpfs      63G  136K   63G   1% /dev/shm
  tmpfs          tmpfs      63G  1.9M   63G   1% /run
  tmpfs          tmpfs      63G     0   63G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
  /dev/sda3      ext4      3.6T  1.4T  2.2T  39% /
  /dev/sda2      ext4      9.8G   57M  9.2G   1% /boot
  tmpfs          tmpfs      13G     0   13G   0% /run/user/480
  tmpfs          tmpfs      13G   16K   13G   1% /run/user/1000
```

How this problem can be solved?

Comment: Are you an older version of the STAR aligner? A similar error has been discussed here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rna-star/OTUG26gKKmo

Comment: You are using 26 threads, while you have 125GB of RAM, this means per thread you have 4.8 GB RAM. Your genome size is 13 GB (according to your previous [post](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/4340/error-creating-indices-using-star)). An answer to your previous post suggested to reduce the number of threads. Did you try to run with lower number of threads?

Comment: @b.nota I ran the job discussed in previous post with same number of threads.

Comment: @Kasper I am using latest version of STAR

Comment: Report the bug on github and sort with samtools.

Comment: @DevonRyan ok I will post it there. Can I use --limitBAMsortRAM to solve this problem?

Comment: @AmmarSabirCheema I don't think so, since any time you need to increase that there's an error message saying so. I think this is just a bug somewhere. Just sort the unsorted output with samtools or sambamba.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

STAR versions 2.6.0b and 2.6.0a are unstable,  as written [Issues performing variant calling with GATK](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/4449/issues-performing-variant-calling-with-gatk) you are using version 2.6.0b. You should switch to version 2.6.0c which is stable.  Also avoid to perform multiple alignments in the same directory.